# Trouble importing tkinter in Karrigell

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to add a python program in an html page and I've settled for Karrigell as it seemed easy to use

our program will be used to time cars and it currently uses tkinter

however, I get this error when I add it in the page:

```
Error in /
Line 23    
from tkinter import *
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

I've tried the following:
- use both `tkinter` and `Tkinter`
- use `import tkinter` and `import Tkinter`

these didn't work, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can't you use tkinter in karrigell, if so, is there any way to constantly update a variable without having the webpage load infinitely?

here's a pastebin with the program: http://pastebin.com/zh3CenY3

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use tkinter in an html page.

Comment: is there any way to update a variable without getting stuck on infinite loading then?

Comment: @Mranth0ny62: yes. Read up on web sockets.